# Unable to get the same time in mobile application which is set in its website

Tags: cordova

My mobile app is showing current timezone instead of displaying timezone set in its website application.
For example:I have used US timezone in my website application then in Mobile App its displaying current timezone instead of showing US timezone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid the question as it is now is not good to answer. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i am making mobile app of my website. I am setting US timezone in my website and i want the same timezone in my mobile app.Now if I open my mobile app then it s showing me the current timezone not US timezone.